# Android share value between apps

Tags: android, process, communication

I want to share small information between Android Apps.
A broadcast intent is too overload and the reading app may not be active at the moment of writing the value. Shared files are no option because apps are not from the same source. We don't know the origin's package name, there is just a unique valuename.
A file in a commonly accessible place - no that's too overload for some bytes only.

A SystemProperty would be the perfect solution - if it wasn't writable as system app only. (ok and via reflection only but that'd be ok)
Are there other means to do this?

Comment: What is wrong with a broadcast intent? That's what is designed for..

Comment: I read **sticky** intents are discouraged. A **not sticky** broadcast doesn't really fit into the concept because the receiving apps probably are not active when it's sent. They'd have to be activated and save the value for later use. But that could be a solution if nothing else is possible.

Comment: what about  [Content Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html)

Comment: wow such an effort to store a small string ... strange!

Comment: if strange then read this: https://developer.android.com/training/building-content-sharing.html